# Is there a way to see where my code is inefficient?

Tags: pycharm

I use Pycharm, and am currently working on a project in Python. Whenever I run it, Pycharm takes close to 1 minute to output the data I want, which is much slower than usual. Clearly the issue is that my code is inefficient in some way, and I am slowing it down. I'm just not sure where. Is there a way to see where the computer is spending the most time processing?

I looked into what Jetbrains might have to offer in regards to code efficiency, but from what I have seen, they only offer paid and professional type software for this. Is there anything built in to the Community Edition of Pycharm, or something free I could download to see where my code is causing issues?

Thanks!

Comment: `python -m cProfile myscript.py` gives some information ([link](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/profile.html)). Try googling "Python profiler" in general, or see [this from pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/profiler.html)

Comment: @Jeppe Thanks, cProfile in particular is very helpful and intuitive

Comment: feel free to add your code if you want input on what the bottleneck may be. There is also a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user recommended I try cProfile. This ended up working perfectly and gave me a great idea of where my code was inefficient and taking long periods of time to execute I found the [instant User Manual](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/profile.html#instant-user-s-manual) for cProfile particularly helpful. Thanks to @Jeppe for helping me out!